How do I get an accurate count of rows of a large table in ScyllaDB?
I have a large table consisting of about 1B rows in ScyllaDB. I need to get a count of rows present in the table for statistical and verification purposes.
If the consistency level(CL) is set to ONE, the count returns with an approximate number. On setting CL to QUORUM, the query times out with various errors:
NoHostAvailable:
OperationTimedOut: errors={'<ip>:9042': 'Client request timeout. See Session.execute[_async](timeout)'}, last_host=<ip>:9042
The query we are running:
CONSISTENCY QUORUM;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TRANSACTIONS USING TIMEOUT 120s;

We have also increased the timeout through read_request_timeout_in_ms in /etc/scylla/scylla.yml but the query behaviour remained the same.
How can I get this accurate count?

Would you try dsbulk count? Check out this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75894136/23191687

One way you can do this is to restrict the query to a part of the token range, as described in the blog post https://www.scylladb.com/2017/02/13/efficient-full-table-scans-with-scylla-1-6/ - for example:
SELECT count(*) FROM transactions WHERE token(id) >= -9204925292781066255 AND token(id) <= -9223372036854775808;

And do those queries in parallel or sequentially, for a set of token ranges that together cover the entire token space.
In recent releases of ScyllaDB, the ordinary count(*) aggregation which you ran already does a similar form of parallelization, internally, but you have little control of how it works or knowledge of how it is progressing. E.g., if it timed out in 120 seconds, you don't know if it finished 90% of the work and just a little bit more would have been enough - or perhaps it only finished 1% of the work and the timeout you need is much higher. If you split the counting work yourself, you have more control and visibility on how the scanning is progressing.
